# como consumir este webservice soapclient em php?

Tags: php, web-service, soap, soapclient

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

como consumir este webservice soapclient em php ???
tentei o código abaixo e deu o seguinte erro.

**Código**

```
$client = new SoapClient('http://www.smsviaweb.com.br/SMSVIAWEB.asmx?wsdl');
  $params = array('Login'    => 'xxxxx', 'Senha'    => 'xxxxx','Telefone'=>'xxxxx', 'Mensagem'=>'xxxxx');
  $client->__soapCall("Envia", $params);
```

**Erro**

> Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [soap:Server]
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to
>   process request. ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference
>   not set to an instance of an object. at SMSVIAWEB.Envia(OBJMsgSMSVW
>   OBJMsg) --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

**getFunctions**

```
 array(6) {
  [0]=>
  string(38) "EnviaResponse Envia(Envia $parameters)"
  [1]=>
  string(50) "EnviaLoteResponse EnviaLote(EnviaLote $parameters)"
  [2]=>
  string(62) "ExecutaImportResponse ExecutaImport(ExecutaImport $parameters)"
  [3]=>
  string(38) "EnviaResponse Envia(Envia $parameters)"
  [4]=>
  string(50) "EnviaLoteResponse EnviaLote(EnviaLote $parameters)"
  [5]=>
  string(62) "ExecutaImportResponse ExecutaImport(ExecutaImport $parameters)"
}
array(9) {
  [0]=>
  string(37) "struct Envia {
 OBJMsgSMSVW OBJMsg;
}"
  [1]=>
  string(127) "struct OBJMsgSMSVW {
 string Login;
 string Senha;
 string IDCliente;
 string Telefone;
 string Mensagem;
 string DataAgenda;
}"
```

Comment: Defina melhor exatamente o que você quer.. Quer o código para conectar o cliente no web service?

Comment: @Andrey isso mesmo.

Comment: Ok, procure primeiro tentar fazer sozinho.... caso não consiga, poste o que vc tentou e a comunidade irá lhe mostrar como melhorar/ajustar o código. Só estou lhe mostrando como usar o site, não leve a mal.

Comment: @Andrey obrigado pela ajuda.. já tentei e mesmo assim não foi. vou postar o código